# WCF REST is failing to deserialize class that implements IXMLSerializable

Tags: c#, api, wcf

I have WCF project that has been converted to rest.
I am having hard time to receiving the right value for a property which its type implements IXMLSerializable

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[XmlType(TypeName = "Dimension")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SharedDimension))]
public class Dimension
{
    [DataMember] 
    public string Id {get;set}

    //[DataMember] 
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Members")]
    public Members Members { get; set; }

    // another properties of Dimension class
}


[Serializable]
 //[XmlSchemaProvider("GetSchema")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[XmlRoot]
 public class Members: IXMLSerializable 
 public List<Member> Items
 {
    get
    {
    //code that use the IXMLSerializable goes here
    }
    set
    {
    //code that use the IXMLSerializable goes here
    }
}

// another properties of Members class


public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return null;
}

[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "Member")]
public class Member : Equatable<Member>, ICodrObject
{
    // properties of Member class
}

public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/ProcessDimensions")]
    bool ProcessDimensions(int productId, List<Dimension> dimensions);

    // another end points
}
public class Service implements IService
{
    bool ProcessDimensions(int productId, List<Dimension> dimensions){
    //  code goes here 
}
```

Calling this endd point from post man, productId,Dimension.Id has the right value but Dimension.Members is NULL

```
{
    "productId": 000000,
    "dimensions": [{
        "Id": "D1",
        "Members": {
            "ID": "M1.1",
            "Items": [{
                "Id": 1
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": "D2",
        "Members": {
            "ID": "M2.1",
            "Items": [{
                "Id": 1
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I am still using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `JSON` data format. Uncomment out the `[DataMember]`statement will solve the issue.

```
//[DataMember] 
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Members")]
public Members Members { get; set; }
```

Although you say you are using `XmlSerializer`, you are actually using the `DataContractSerializer` throughout the service.
`DataContractSerializer` is the default serializer in WCF, which includes the class which is without decorating with `[DataContract]`. If we want to manually switch to the `XmlSerializer`, we are supposed to use `[XmlSerializerFormat]` to decorate the service contract.
For details,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
Please remove relevant `XMlserializer` attributes, it might interfere with the `DataContractSerializer`. Please consider the below definition.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Dimension
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Members Members { get; set; }

    }

    //DataContractSerializer is the serializer by default.
    public class Members
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<Member> Items { get; set; }    
    }
    public class Member 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried this but the Member field is alway null. I alo tried converting my endpoint to accept xml instead but when i consume the end from post man it is telling that it is invalid xml when the xml is valid.

Comment: I enabled help page of webhttp and I dont see I can provide data for Members.

Comment: Please consider my above definition of the Data Contract.

Comment: ISerializable, is very importanto us and dont want to duplicate the classes without ISerializable. Ended up sending it to WCF as string and serialized it my self. I tried similar approach as you suggested but I was having troubles with the deserialization (namespace and nil). thanks for being patience with me